# Weird NameError: global name 'StrList' is not defined

Tags: python, global-variables

I have this code that I think looks ok

```
def makeInverseIndex(strList):
    numStrList = list(enumerate(strList))
    n = 0
    dictionary = {}
    while (n < len(strList)):
        for word in numStrList[n][1].split():
            if word not in dictionary:
                dictionary[word] = {numStrList[n][0]}
            elif {numStrList[n][0]} not in dictionary[word]:
                dictionary[word]|={numStrList[n][0]} 
        n = n+1                     

    return dictionary
```

But I manage to get this error when I try to run the module:

```
   >>> makeInverseIndex(L)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./inverse_index_lab.py", line 21, in makeInverseIndex
    for word in numStrList[n][1].split():
NameError: global name 'StrList' is not defined
```

I do not see where the error can come from.

I want to input something like this:

```
 L=['A B C', 'B C E', 'A E', 'C D A']
```

and get this as output:

```
D={'A':{0,2,3}, 'B':{0,1}, 'C':{0,3}, 'D':{3}, 'E':{1,2}}
```

Comment: Fix the indentation in the question.

Comment: That is exactly what it returns. Are you sure? When I run it I get this `{'A': set([0, 2, 3]), 'C': set([0, 1, 3]), 'B': set([0, 1]), 'E': set([1, 2]), 'D': set([3])}
`

Comment: @enginefree, Python3 displays the sets differently. but the value for `C` in the question still seems wrong

Comment: @gnibbler But `C` is included in `0,1,3` indices and not just in `0,3`.

Comment: @enginefree, that's what I meant when I said "in the question". Sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have modified the module without reloading it.

The traceback is showing you the current content of the line from the source file, which may differ from when you loaded the module.